# XNA change screen when button sound effect ends

Tags: button, xna, soundeffect

I working on platformer game. I got menu screen and few buttons there. I have problem with "StarGame" button, because after click I want to play sound effect first and than move to gamescreen.

My buttonclick event looks like this:

```
effect.Play(DebuggingVariables.Volume, 0, 0); 
this.MoveToScreen(typeof(GameScreen).FullName);
```

effect starts to play, but immediatly move to gamescreen.

I'm using FlatRedBall engine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the duration of the sound effect via `SoundEffect.Duration` and start counting time passed with something like `timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds`. Once `timer` is bigger than the duration, you can then call your `MoveToScreen()` method.